# AWS App Runner deploy failing

Tags: amazon-web-services

I'm playing with AWS App Runner and I'm having issues with deployments/service updates. Half of the deployments fail with no apparent reason. A few minutes after the deployment is initiated, the app is actually deployed, but then, after 20-30 minutes, it rolls back to the previous version.

I've been trying to find something useful in cloudwatch, but no luck, it doesn't log anything (hey, Amazon, it would be reeealy useful to log the reason why the deployment failed) except for `deployment started` and `deployment failed`. The healthcheck endpoint is `/`, there's an apache2 instance in the container and it returns 200. I even set the healthcheck timeout to very generous 5s and 10 retries, but it didn't help.

I feel like I'm out of options. Nothing useful in the logs, the app inside the container is healthy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found out that it's an AWS issue, they are going on a fix, however, there's a workaround – you can remove custom domains and deploys should work.